# How to select rows and update them without concurrency issues?

Tags: php, mysql, select, transactions, sql-update

I am implementing a queue with PHP and MySQL 5.6.17 (InnoDB) and I want to select the first N matching rows and then mark them as being processed.

I need the rows to be marked as being processed because the query is executed by multiple scripts running in parallel (so I need to prevent the scripts from selecting the same rows).

I wrote the following query:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE col4 = 1 AND date_update_started < UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
ORDER BY col5 DESC, col6 ASC
LIMIT 100 FOR UPDATE;

#update the above selected rows to mark them as being processed
UPDATE table SET date_update_started = UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id, col2, col3 #same query as above
    FROM table
    WHERE col4 = 1 AND date_update_started < UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
    ORDER BY col5 DESC, col6 ASC
    LIMIT 100
);

COMMIT;
```

However, when testing the update part of the query I receive the following error:

> [Err] 1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

How can this query be modified so that it selects the first N matching rows and updates the `date_update_started` column on those rows so that they are not selected by scripts executing this query in parallel?

Comment: Have you tried a sub-sub query? That has fixed similar problems for me in MySQL. Select everything without a limit from a subquery table with a limit.

Comment: @halfer MySQL 5.6.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure each instance of the script has an unique ID. You can pass it as a command line parameter when it runs.

Add a column to your queue table:

- `scriptId INT DEFAULT NULL` - use it to lock some rows; keep the ID of the script that locks them.

This code locks some rows:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET lockId = 123    # Replace '123' (in PHP) with the ID of the script that runs the query
WHERE lockId IS NULL
   AND ...  # put your own conditions here to select the entries you want to process
LIMIT 100   # change '100' with the number of entries you want to lock in a batch
```

Then run:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE lockId = 123    # The same value as above
```

to get the locked rows.

After each row is processed you either remove it from the table or set a status field as 'processed' and use it to filter it out in the locking query above.

**Remark:** This approach works well if you are **absolutely sure** the processing script never crashes during the processing. If it crashes it leaves the rows locked. If on the next run it uses the same `script ID` it will attempt to process the locked rows then. This can be fixed by unlocking the rows when the scripts exits.

Comment: The scripts unfortunately throw errors and sometimes run into fatal errors quite often, but I think if your approach were combined with the date_update_started column it might work.

Comment: Is there an elegant way to accomplish this using select for update?  @nate did you find a way to write the script to allow graceful restart after crash? Can you simply first select for rows lingering from a previous run, assuming a constant script ID of course.